# Why Canon printer is not allowed to be connected to PC before installing the software?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I have bought brand new Canon i-sensys LBP113w and I am going to connect it to my Windows 7 x32 computer, hoping that Windows will install drivers from Internet as usual. But something is bothering me - the USB input hole is sealed with a bright sticker that says "Do not connect the USB cable before installing the software". Why? That sticker so bothers me that I can not start to print. My guess is that the software on Canon's CD contains some spyware or adware, while drivers from Windows' source of drivers does not, and Canon just wants to steal some data from as many PCs as possible.
[photo of the sticker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOfcx.jpg)

Any other possible assumptions?

Comment: You seem to have chosen the absolutely least likely explanation for their requirement. Why not pick another?

Answer (score 3):

A company like Canon should be spared from conspiration theories.

Evidently, Canon does not want Windows to install its own driver, but most probably
because the generic Windows driver does not fully support the printer.
So Canon wants its driver installed first, to avoid you later contacting its Support
complaining that "my new printer doesn't work well".

If because of unbased theories you prefer to not use fully the features of your
printer, go ahead and ignore this sticker. By doing so you may void your warranty,
if that makes you feel safer.